# SSL error on Django app for Heroku deployment

Tags: django, ssl, heroku

I am trying to setup SSL for my Django app, using Heroku to deploy, and am getting an "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:24466" when I run the "$ curl -v https://localhost:24466/" request from my local machine (ie cutting out the entire Heroku stack). My app runs fine on Heroku when DEBUG = True but gets a connection error when DEBUG = False and I believe this is the issue.

Here are the relevant settings I am using in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Does anything look wrong for deployment with DEBUG=False?

Here is the full result from "$ curl -v https://localhost:24466/":

```
~ $ curl -v https://localhost:24466/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 24466 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
[2016-12-01 16:49:39 +0000] [18] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:24466 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:24466 
[2016-12-01 11:49:39 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
[2016-12-01 16:49:39 +0000] [33] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33
```

Comment: When DEBUG=FALSE, you're supposed to be using nginx or apache for SSL termination and wither WSGI or gunicorn for running django.  Which setup are you using?

Comment: I'm using gunicorn for running django and am not using nginx or apache for SSL...I'll look into it I guess.